# In Swift, should I write a separate class for handling a UI component?

Tags: swift, oop

I am new to OOP and Swift. I have some code like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var topMenuScrollView: UIScrollView!

    topMenu_doSomething1()
    topMenu_doSomething2()
    topMenu_doSomething3()
    ...
}
```

topMenu is a scrollView I have to do many things with. I found I have to write a lot of code for this top menu in this view controller file. Therefore, should I create a new class (a new swift file) specifically for the top menu handling?

However, I only have one top menu. Is it correct to write a class for it? (because I won't have multiple instances)

What's the right way to arrange this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of object-oriented design is as much code-reuse as it is code-comprehensibility. In your case, it sounds like your menu has a lot of detailed behavior which is specific to that menu. Well, imagine at some point you want to change or rewrite the menu; it will certainly be easier if that logic is clearly isolated.

It sounds like this is a good case for another class, but it's entirely up to you.

Comment: Yes, I can understand the benefit to make it isolated. I just have an impression that class is used for multiple instances. Therefore, in this case, the menu is not going to have multiple instance, so I feel it's kind of weird to have a separated class file for it.

Comment: Again, code reuse is only one tenant of object oriented design. Isolating the menu into its own class, with a decent method API, will ensure that the views (or view) presenting the menu never need to know how the menu works. Just insert and go. Generally speaking, this is highly desirable.